# localhost/127.0.0.1 - This site can’t be reached

Tags: macos, apache, vhosts, dnsmasq

Installed and setup dnsmasq / apache vhosts, localhost say, "This site can’t be reached". Followed these tutorials [https://mallinson.ca/osx-web-development/](https://www.fourkitchens.com/blog/article/local-development-apache-vhosts-and-dnsmasq/), https://mallinson.ca/osx-web-development/

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
UseCanonicalName Off

httpd-vhosts.conf

LogFormat "%V %h %l %u %t "%r" %s %b "%{Referer}i" "%{User-Agent}i"" dynamic_vhosts
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access_log dynamic_vhosts
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  VirtualDocumentRoot /Users/jharri34/Sites/%0

  <Directory "/Users/jharri34/Sites">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think You should add this line into Your `httpd-vhosts.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: added still the same I've added the httpd-vhost.conf file in the original question. I have the file sitting in ~/Sites/httpd-vhost.conf and have soft-linked it to /etc/apache2/extra and /etc/apache2/other

Comment: There seems to be two places with apache config /etc/apache2/ and /private/etc/apache2 which to added vhost file to

Comment: You lunch Your `APACHE` server